# Magento 2.4.2 EE to 2.4.3 EE issue

Tags: magento-upgrade, magento2.4.3

After upgarde from magento enterprice 2.4.2 to 2.4.3 I am unable to execute setup:upgrade command.

I am getting below error for many tables.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key, query was: ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity` DROP PRIMARY KEY, DROP KEY `CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ROW_ID`, ADD CONSTRAINT  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`,`row_id`)
```

Can anyone help me to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the issue with below tables.

> 'catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity','widget_instance_page_layout','catalog_url_rewrite_product_category','quote_preview','oauth_nonce','magento_customersegment_event','magento_catalogpermissions_index','magento_catalogpermissions_index_product','magento_catalogpermissions_index_tmp','magento_catalogpermissions_index_product_tmp','catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video','magento_reward_salesrule','magento_salesrule_filter'

So I have created a custom console command module to remove that primary key and it worked fine.

Here is the code which I used in the console command file.

> Note: Direct use of objectmanager is not recommended but as it just 1 time use is have used in my code

```
private $_objectManager;


private $state;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,
    $name = null
)
{
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->state = $state;
    parent::__construct($name);
}
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    
    $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND); // or \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, depending on your needs

    $resource = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');

    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tbaleNames = array('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity','widget_instance_page_layout','catalog_url_rewrite_product_category','quote_preview','oauth_nonce','magento_customersegment_event','magento_catalogpermissions_index','magento_catalogpermissions_index_product','magento_catalogpermissions_index_tmp','magento_catalogpermissions_index_product_tmp','catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_video','magento_reward_salesrule','magento_salesrule_filter');
    
    //$table = $connection->getTableName('');
    foreach ($tbaleNames as $value) {
         $query = "ALTER TABLE `" . $value . "` DROP `id`";
        $connection->query($query);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is small changes in query "ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> DROP COLUMN <column_name>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, because table `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity` had other primary key, that have been added manually, to optimize the table.

So what I can recommend:

- check what columns you have in this table
- if you have columns, that not described in Magento db_schema.xml, remove it

---

In my case, I had additional column `epid` PRIMARY KEY, I run query directly in DB, that Magento2 upgrade try to with additional `DROP COLUMN epid` and it fixed it.
My query:

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    DROP COLUMN epid,
    DROP KEY `CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_TO_ENTT_VAL_ID_ENTT_ID`,
    ADD CONSTRAINT PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`, `entity_id`),
    DEFAULT CHARSET = 'utf8',
    DEFAULT COLLATE = 'utf8_general_ci';
```