# Mysql error MySQL doesn't yet support drop existing primary key without adding a new primary key

Tags: magento2, database, setup-upgrade, deployment

need help regarding the issue, All of the sudden our production environment we are getting issue during upgrade command

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'existing primary key drop without adding a new primary key. In @@sql_generate_invisible_primary_key=ON mode table should have a primary key. Please add a new primary key to be able to drop existing primary key.', query was: ALTER TABLE `widget_instance_page_layout` DEFAULT CHARSET='utf8', DEFAULT COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
```

i tried to fix using this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/352307/78648  but i am getting issue in lot of tables

i cant reproduce the issue on any other enviorment

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Mysql issue rather than Magento. Try the following command:

```
mysql> SET sql_generate_invisible_primary_key=OFF;
```

[You can check the solution from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/concepts-limitations)